# Automate End to End Test of Google.Com through Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, end-to-end

I am trying to make Protractor go to google.com and search a term.

1. I have come to where protractor loads the non angular page Google
   and then puts the text in. How do I make it press "enter" or click
   the button?
2. In addition I am not finding any guides on how to write protractor
   tests and the functions available? I am also new to JS and Angular.
   Should I learn more AngularJS concepts or Protractor Concepts?

spec.js:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
describe('Enter Search Term', function() {
 it('This will insert into the text field in google.com', function() {
 browser.get('www.google.com');
 element(by.xpath('//*[@id="q"]')).sendKeys('What is Protractor?');
  var query = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="q"]'));
expect(query = 'What is Protractor?');
browser.pause();
  });
});
```

conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
};
```

Comment: Use `.click()` or `.sendKeys(key.ENTER)`. The API is available [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api). You'll find some examples in the  [code repository](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.2.0)

Comment: Yes, please review the API.  They have a tutorial and plenty of documentation with examples there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping the page links by xpath does the job.

https://github.com/SDasman/Angular_Protractor_End2End_Tests/tree/master/Protractor_Google